# NSScrollView loses documentview after performing Segue

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsscrollview

I'm developing an Mac OS X Application with Storyboards. I've got a NSScrollview on my main controller. That's how it's content is created:

```
-(void)addProduktWithName: (NSString *)NameStr Price: (CGFloat)PriceFl TimesOfProduct: (CGFloat)TOfPFl{

    [MainView setFrameSize: NSSizeFromCGSize(CGSizeMake(ProductScrollView.contentSize.width, (CellsCount + 1) * 25))];

    NSFont *StandardFont = [NSFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica" size: 18];

    //Strings
    NSString *NumberStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", CellsCount + 1];
    NSString *PriceStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", PriceFl];
    NSString *TOfPStr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", TOfPFl];

    NSImageView *PositionCell = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, CellsCount * 25, 45, 25)];
    [PositionCell setImageScaling: NSImageScaleAxesIndependently];
    [PositionCell setImage: [NSImage imageNamed: @"TableCell3"]];
    [MainView addSubview: PositionCell];

    NSImageView *CellStyle = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(45, CellsCount * 25, ProductScrollView.contentSize.width - 45, 25)];
    [CellStyle setImageScaling: NSImageScaleAxesIndependently];

    if ((CellsCount % 2) == 0) {
        [CellStyle setImage: [NSImage imageNamed: @"TableCell"]];
    } else {
        [CellStyle setImage: [NSImage imageNamed: @"TableCell2"]];
    }
    [MyView addSubview: CellStyle];

    NSTextField *Index = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, CellsCount * 25, 45, 25)];
    [Index setStringValue: NumberStr];
    [Index setFont: StandardFont];
    [Index setBezeled:NO];
    [Index setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [Index setEditable:NO];
    [Index setSelectable:NO];
    [Index setAlignment: NSCenterTextAlignment];
    [MainView addSubview: Index];

    NSTextField *Number = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(60, CellsCount * 25, 45, 25)];
    [Number setStringValue: TOfPStr];
    [Number setFont: StandardFont];
    [Number setBezeled:NO];
    [Number setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [Number setEditable:NO];
    [Number setSelectable:NO];
    [Number setAlignment: NSCenterTextAlignment];
    [MainView addSubview: Number];

    NSTextField *Product = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(105, CellsCount * 25, ProductScrollView.contentSize.width - 205, 25)];
    [Product setStringValue: NameStr];
    [Product setFont: StandardFont];
    [Product setBezeled:NO];
    [Product setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [Product setEditable:NO];
    [Product setSelectable:NO];
    [Product setAlignment: NSLeftTextAlignment];
    [MainView addSubview: Product];

    NSTextField *Price = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(ProductScrollView.contentSize.width - 100, CellsCount * 25, 100, 25)];
    [Price setStringValue: [PriceStr stringByAppendingString: @" €"]];
    [Price setFont: StandardFont];
    [Price setBezeled:NO];
    [Price setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [Price setEditable:NO];
    [Price setSelectable:NO];
    [Price setAlignment: NSRightTextAlignment];
    [MainView addSubview: Price];

    [ProductScrollView setDocumentView: MainView];

    CellsCount += 1;

}
```

Now I'm performing a Segue to the "Pay"-ViewController, and I'm permitting the MainView to that Controller, so that the View can be shown there.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(NSStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString: @"ShowPay"]) {
        [segue.destinationController setProductView: MainView];
    }
}
```

In my Pay-View:

```
-(void)setProductView:(NSView *)myView{
    ProductView = myView;
}
```

Now, if the user wants to cancel the payment, and edit it, he can click a button, and my Main Controller will be shown again. But the content of the Scrollview is only shown, if I'm calling the addProduct-Method. (You know, thats not what I want, because, then he adds a product and I have to tab onto a button to show my ScrollView again!)
The MainView isn't loosed. Everything is still existing but the scrollview isn't showing it anymore! Maybe there's a method, which is called, after dismissing a controller, where I can set up the document view again...

Thank you for any Help!

Comment: Why did you tagged your question with both `iOS` and `OSX`?

Comment: Your code is difficult to follow because you're capitalizing variable names as though they were class names. While that doesn't explain why it's not working as you're expecting, it does make it more challenging to debug. If you change your code to normal coding guidelines, where variables always begin with a lowercase letter, perhaps more people will offer solutions.